# Change parallax banner size on mobile

Tags: css, size, parallax, banner, squarespace

I had a really good experience on this blog a few months ago so I'm hoping someone will be kind enough to help me again :)

I am working on a website on Squarespace and have an issue with the banners on mobile. Here's my website: https://sim-zuk-zrdc.squarespace.com

The problem I'm experiencing is that the banner zooms in too much on the image on mobile, cutting off important parts of the image.

So I found a code that showed them full size. However it adds additional padding I don't want. Here's the code that is getting me half way there:

```css
 @media only screen 
 and (max-width: 640px)
 { .image-container.content-fill { max-height: 300px; }}
```

If you check on your mobiles, the images are now full size but now I'm getting these horrible, big white spaces. (I've also attached a picture[CLICK ME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JmSD.png))

Does anyone know how to fix this? PLEAAAAAAASE :)

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Please help!!! :(

Answer (score 0):

You're using the [Marquee template](https://marquee-demo.squarespace.com/#about-marquee) right?

The reason you're seeing the white space or bands between your parallax images is that you're only controlling the height of the images container `<div>` and not the `<img>` itself.

The `content-fill` class in Squarespace is a class used by Squarespace's [ImageLoader](https://developers.squarespace.com/imageloader/) YUI (javascript) image loading and cropping utility that dynamically sizes the image to fit its container.

Because of this you can only control the size of the container and not the `<img>` itself unless you turn on Squarespace's Developer mode. I'm pretty sure you'd have to customize the template files for Marquee's index view removing the content-fill class and adding an ImageLoader class for the correct mobile size and then using YUI/js to reload the images when the window is resized.

Are you using Developer mode?